Ranked voting method that accounts for the sample size of a particular comparison?
If there are 2 competing products on Amazon, and one has an average rating of 4.5 (by 2 people) and one has an average rating of 4.49 (by 10000 people), I'll obviously choose the second product with the better sample size. A simple rule of thumb that takes into account sample size is to take the average rating, and subtract off some constant times $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ (where $n$ is the sample size).
Similarly, as an extreme ranked-choice voting example: there are 4 choices (A, B, C, D). 9997 people vote that A > B > C (and don't know where to put D). 1 person votes A > D. 2 people vote that D > A. And so the final ordering you end up with is D > A > B > C. But the number of votes that compared D and anything else were hardly any, so this isn't exactly an ideal ranking, as it doesn't take into account sample size/statistical significance.
Is there a more "robust" ranked choice voting scheme that gives some kind of weight to sample size?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/141988/2921, https://janhove.github.io/posts/2024-09-10-contingency-p-value/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_paradox, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitivity#Cycles

https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html, https://web.archive.org/web/20150306032127/http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10882/2921, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/182405/2921
